# In the given figure, $AD||BC||EF$.....

Tags: geometry

In the given figure, $AD||BC||EF$, $AB||DE$ & $BE||AF$. Prove that :$||gm ABCD=||gm BEFG$[image]

Attempt

Joining $BD$, I got:

$$\triangle ABD=\triangle BCG$$
If $AG$ intersects $BD$ at $O$
$$\triangle AOB +\triangle AOD=\triangle BOG+quad. OGCD$$

Now what should I do next?

Comment: Do you mean we have to prove that the parallelogram $ABCD$ is congruent to the parallelogram $BEFG$?

Answer (score 1):

I will use the following somewhat common notation:

$[ABCD]$ denotes the area of whatever shape $ABCD$ is (this extends to any number of letters).

Because the area of a parallelogram is base times height, if the bases are the same and the heights are the same, then the area is the same.  Then:

Let $H$ be the intersection of $\overline{AF}$ and $\overline{ED}.$

Treating $\overline{AB}$ as a common base, we get

$$[ABCD]=[ABEH]$$

beacuse they have the same height.

Similarly, treating $\overline{BE}$ as a common base gives

$$[ABEH]=[BEFG],$$

as desired.